# Return JSON data from AJAX post in Flask Python Route

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask

Hey guys I need to be able to return json data from ajax post in Flask. I've only been able to return the data with a global list declared, and appending the post data to the global list, in which I'm pretty sure you can see how this is not good.

**Here is what the route looks like that works**:

```
data = []
@app.route('/pricing/orders/<user_name>/api', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def api(user_name):
    user_name = current_user.username
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data.append(json.loads(request.form["javascript_data"]))
    return jsonify(data)
```

**I would like to return the data directly from route variable, like so:**

```
@app.route('/pricing/orders/<user_name>/api', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def api(user_name):
    data = []
    user_name = current_user.username
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data.append(json.loads(request.form["javascript_data"]))
    return jsonify(data)
```

**Here is the Ajax code if needed**

```
$.post('/pricing/orders/' + username + '/api', {
javascript_data: JSON.stringify({[equipmentName]:equipmentPrice})
```

});

**Complete JS Code**

```
var tablerows = document.getElementById('table').rows.length;
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var cart = document.getElementById('cart');
var subtotal = document.getElementById('subtotal');
var username = document.getElementById('username').innerHTML;
var pricesub = document.getElementById('pricefooter');

// On load cart
window.onload = function wowzers(){
  var array = [];
  var sum = 0;
  // Get Data
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'pricing/orders/' + username +'/api', true);
  xhr.onload = function(){
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

    if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400){
      for(x in data){
        for(key in data[x]){
          array.push(Number(data[x][key]));
          sum+=Number(data[x][key]);
          subtotal.innerHTML = sum;
          row = cart.insertRow(-1);
          // Delete Data
          row.addEventListener('click', function deleterow(){
            index = this.rowIndex;
            $.post('pricing/orders/delete', {
              delete_item: index
            });
             cart.deleteRow(index);
             subtotal.innerHTML = sum-Number(cart.rows[index].cells[1].innerHTML);
          });
          cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          cell1.innerHTML = key;
          cell2. innerHTML = data[x][key];
          cell3. innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>"
        }
      }
      console.log(sum);
    }else{
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  xhr.send()
}

//Dynamic Cart
for(x = 0; x < tablerows; x++){
  table.rows[x].addEventListener('click', addCartItem);
}
function addCartItem(ev){
  var array = [];
  var priceData = {};

  var sum = 0;
  index = this.rowIndex;
  equipmentCell = table.rows[index].cells[0];
  priceCell = table.rows[index].cells[1];
  equipmentName = equipmentCell.innerHTML;
  equipmentPrice = priceCell.innerHTML;

  // Post Data
  $.post('/pricing/orders/' + username + '/api', {
    javascript_data: JSON.stringify({[equipmentName]:equipmentPrice})
  });
  cartrow = cart.insertRow(-1);
  // Delete Data
  cartrow.addEventListener('click', function deleterow(){
    index = this.rowIndex;
    subtotal.innerHTML = sum-Number(cart.rows[index].cells[1].innerHTML);
    $.post('pricing/orders/delete', {
      delete_item: index
    });
    cart.deleteRow(index);
  });
  cell1 = cartrow.insertCell(0);
  cell2 = cartrow.insertCell(1);
  cell3 = cartrow.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML= equipmentName;
  cell2.innerHTML = equipmentPrice;
  cell3.innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>";
  // Open Api information
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'pricing/orders/' + username +'/api', true);
  xhr.onload = function(){
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400){
      for(x in data){  
        for(y in data[x]){
          array.push(Number(data[x][y]));
          sum+=Number(data[x][y]);
          subtotal.innerHTML = sum;
        }
      }
    }else{
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

I've tried returning 'json.loads(request.from["javascript_data"])' directly but doesn't work either. Not sure of how to do this. I'm a noob so please help if possible!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Neither of these would work because you don't have anything called javascript_data in the posted data. But just moving the declaration of the list wouldn't help.

Comment: The route you're sending the Ajax request to doesn't match the one you've shown us

Comment: `data.append(json.loads(request.form["javascript_data"])))` why? That's just sending the request data right back. This is pointless.

Comment: Shoots sorry guys I sent the wrong code snippet check edits. The reason I'm trying to do this is so I can use an XMLHttp request in js code to grab data from that url.

Comment: You've made a hash of your AJAX as far as I can see and have no way to process the python response. I think this is in the category of "play a bit more first" :)

Comment: Thanks RoganJosh I was hoping y'all could help figure out why it's working with a global variable and not a local one. And I definitely agree I need to play a little more with it haha. What do you mean by hash of Ajax btw, sorry just really trying to get steered in the right direction.